# How to compare values of different columns in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm doing a QA where I need to compare many landings pages from two different domains and check if certain IDs are in both sites.

I've done the scrape and so far I have a dataframe like this:
(Sorry if I'm not using the correct format to display df, it's my first time asking a question here and i don't know how to do it properly)

```
  STAGE-1001-1001     PROD-1001-1001      STAGE-1001-1002     PRODs-1001-1002
0     ab1311             ab1311                qa1311               qa1311   
1     ac1312             ac1312                qq1311               qq1311   
2     ad1311             ad1311                qc1313               qc1313   
3     acb1313            acb1313               qd1312               qd1312   
4     a1311              a1311                 qe131e               qe131e
```

Basically, what I need to do is compare STAGE column vs PROD column for each product, in this case STAGE-1001-1001 vs PROD-1001-1001 & PROD-1001-1002 vs PROD-1001-1002

Any thoughts?

My idea is to (once finished) have a df similar to this:

```
             TRUE    FALSE
1001-1001    True
1001-1002    True
1001-1003            False
1001-1004    True    
...
```

Being True if IDs are the same and False if theres any ID missing.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way of doing it (far less *pandastic* than yatu's answer)

```py
# Get product IDs if you don't have them yet
products = {col.split('-', 1)[-1] for col in df.columns}

products_validity = dict()

for prod_id in products:
    is_valid = (df['PROD-'+prod_id]==df['STAGE-'+prod_id]).all()
    products_validity[prod_id] = [is_valid]

validity_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    products_validity, 
    orient='index', 
    columns=['is_valid']
)
# Create inversed column if needed
validity_df['is_not_valid'] = ~validity_df['is_valid']
```